# 3rd degree polynomial fraction decomposition

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

Was solving some differential equations and came upon this integral:

$$\int\frac 1{x(x+1)^2} dx$$

Looked it up on wolframalpha and it can be decomposed to:

$$\frac 1x-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}-\frac{1}{x+1}$$

How do we proceed to decompose polynomials of degree bigger than $2$?

Comment: I usually start by looking for roots.

Comment: $$\dfrac1{(x+a)^m(x+b)^n}=\sum_{r=0}^m\dfrac{A_r}{(x+a)^r}+\sum_{s=0}^n\dfrac{B_s}{(x+b)^s}$$ etc.

Comment: Could you give me an example of the process for the integral I've written?

Comment: You might want to look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac 1x-\color{red}{\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}}-\frac{1}{x+1}$$

Why do you want to proceed to decompose?, you can solve it easly.

$$\int\frac 1x dx-\color{red}{\int \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}dx}-\int \frac{1}{x+1}dx$$

$$=\ln|x|+\frac{1}{x+1}-\ln|x+1|+C$$

---

For $\color{red}{\int \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}dx}$

Set: $t=x+1$ and $dt=dx$

$$\int\frac{1}{t^2}dt\Longrightarrow =-\frac{1}{t}+C=-\frac{1}{x+1}+C$$

---

For fraction with this form

$$\frac{P(x)}{ (x+2)(x+3)^5}$$

the decompose should looks like:

$${A \over x+2}+{B \over x+3}+{C \over (x+3)^2}+{D \over (x+3)^3}+{E \over (x+3)^4}+{F \over (x+3)^5}$$

Comment: You misread the integral. The integral I posted gives us that decomposition which is easy to solve but I want to know how to get there.

Comment: @Sadem I edited, take a look if it's helps or not