# Integrate $\int{\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)^2(x+3)^3}dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate this

> $$\int{\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)^2(x+3)^3}dx}$$

I tried to use that 
$$\int{\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)^2(x+3)^3}dx} = P_{1}(x)/Q_{1}(x) + \int{P_{2}(x)/Q_{2}(x)dx}$$ where $$\frac{P_{1}(x)}{Q_{1}(x)}=\frac{ax^2+bx+c}{(x+2)(x+3)^2}$$ and $$\frac{P_{2}(x)}{Q_{2}(x)}= \frac{dx^2+kx+m}{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)}$$ but I got terrible coeff a,b,c,d,k,m.
 Is there an easier way?

Comment: why dont you just do a partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653359/3rd-degree-polynomial-fraction-decomposition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write
$$\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)^2(x+3)^3}=\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{B}{x+2}+\frac{C}{(x+2)^2}+\frac{D}{(x+3)}+\frac{E}{(x+3)^2}+\frac{F}{(x+3)^3}$$
Solve for $A,B,C,D,E,F$ by comparing coefficients and integrate each term separately.

Comment: As I know it have to be $Cx+c, Ex+e$, and $Fx^2 + f_{1}x+f_{2}$ instead just C, E, F and it doesnt seem to be easier.

Comment: @Denis Actually, these just have to be $C,E,F$ because denominators are powers of degree one polynomial. You would need $Cx+c$ in case the denominator was a degree two polynomial or a power of such.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Write as

$$\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)^2(x+3)^3}=\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{B}{x+2}+\frac{C}{(x+2)^2}+\frac{D}{(x+3)}+\frac{E}{(x+3)^2}+\frac{F}{(x+3)^3}$$

The partial fraction expansion is:

$$\frac{2}{x+2}-\frac{17}{8(x+3)}-\frac{1}{(x+2)^2}-\frac{5}{4(x+3)^2}-\frac{1}{2(x+3)^3}+\frac{1}{8(x+1)}$$

Answer (score 1):

For an alternative approach write the required integral in the form $\int{\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+a)^2(x+b)^3}dx}$ then use $\frac{1}{(x+a)^2} = - \frac{d}{da} \frac{1}{x+a}$ and similarly for $\frac{1}{(x+b)^3}$ in terms of $\frac{d^2}{d b^2} \frac{1}{x+b}$, so that you have to first evaluate $I(a,b) = \int{\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+a)(x+b)}dx}$. The required integral is $\frac{d}{d a} \frac{d^2}{d b^2} I(a,b)$, finally setting $a = 2$, $b = 3$.